# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass when rendering from a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time I try to render something that is located from a different view, I get a NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.
It happens when I put the following code in the view I want to render stuff on:

views/uploads/myuploads.html.erb

```
<%= render template: 'guitar_sounds/index' %>
```

And it tells me that the error seems to be in a particular block of code where the template is located:

views/guitar_sounds/index.html.erb

```
    <% @guitar_sounds.each do |sound| %> <!-- Error here -->
           <%= render "guitar_sound", sound:sound %>
    <% end %>
```

However, when I load that page view on its own, I get no errors.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add locations of those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a partial does not automatically hit a controller method. By that, it sounds like the only controller method being run is `uploads#myuploads`, but your `@guitar_sounds` variable is being defined in `guitar_sounds#index`. I'd simply define the `@guitar_sounds` variable in your `UploadsController`

```
UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def myuploads
    # here is where @guitar_sounds needs to be defined
    @guitar_sounds = GuitarSound.all
  end
end
```

Let's say you needed `@guitar_sounds` in lots of methods, you could define it in a `before_action`

```
UploadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_guitar_sounds
  def myuploads
    # normal controller code
  end

  private

  def set_guitar_sounds
    @guitar_sounds = GuitarSound.all
  end
end
```

Now `@guitar_sounds` will be set for every method in the `UploadsController`

Answer (score 0):

Your template *guitar_sounds/index* expects `@guitar_sounds` to be defined, and be able to iterate over its items.

If you reuse the template without assigning any values to `@guitar_sounds`, by default it will be `nil`, thus you can see the error.

Hope it clarifies a bit the problem!

Answer (score 0):

guitar_sounds/index expects @guitar_sounds to be defined, aka, not nil, so it can iterate over its items.

You should, instead, use local variables.

```
<%= render template: 'guitar_sounds/index', guitar_sounds: @guitar_sounds %> #or other @ variable
```

And at your view:

```
<% guitar_sounds.each do |sound| %> 
       <%= render "guitar_sound", sound:sound %>
<% end %>
```

Now guitar_sounds (note the missing @) is a local variable that you pass to the render function!

EDIT: Check rails documentation about this: [Passing Local Variables to partials/templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).